# How to correct calculation error on Python

Tags: python-3.x, calculation

The following equations estimate the calories burned when exercising (source):

Men: `Calories = [(Age x 0.2017) — (Weight x 0.09036) + (Heart Rate x 0.6309) — 55.0969] x Time / 4.184`

Women: `Calories = [(Age x 0.074) — (Weight x 0.05741) + (Heart Rate x 0.4472) — 20.4022] x Time / 4.184`

Write a program using inputs age (years), weight (pounds), heart rate (beats per minute), and time (minutes). Output calories burned for men and women.

Ex: If the input is:

```
49
155
148
60
```

Then the output is:

```
Men: 489.7772466539196 calories
Women: 580.939531548757 calories
```

My code -

```
age_years = float(input('Enter your age in years:\n'))
weight_lbs = float(input('Enter your weight in pounds:\n'))
heart_rate = float(input('Enter your heart rate in beats per minute:\n'))
time_min = float(input('Enter total time in minutes:\n'))
men_calories = [(age_years * 0.2017) - (weight_lbs * 0.09036) + (heart_rate * 0.6309) - 55.0969] * (time_min / 4.184)
women_calories = [(age_years * 0.074) - (weight_lbs * 0.05741) + (heart_rate * 0.4472) - 20.4022] * (time_min / 4.184)
print("Men:" , men_calories)
```

```
Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
    men_calories = [(age_years * 0.2017) - (weight_lbs * 0.09036) + (heart_rate * 0.6309) - 55.0969] * (time_min / 4.184)
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

In Python, `[]` are used to define lists (sometimes called arrays in other languages), not as separators for expressions such as `()`, so, just use parentheses instead:

```
...
men_calories = ((age_years * 0.2017) - (weight_lbs * 0.09036) + (heart_rate * 0.6309) - 55.0969) * (time_min / 4.184)
women_calories = ((age_years * 0.074) - (weight_lbs * 0.05741) + (heart_rate * 0.4472) - 20.4022) * (time_min / 4.184)
...
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. But zybook is messing with me  and saying its wrong :(

Input
49
155
148
60

Your output

Men: 489.77724665391963 calories
Women: 580.939531548757 calories

Expected output

Men: 489.7772466539196 calories
Women: 580.939531548757 calories

Answer (score 0):

If you use the following expression it will round your answer up to the nearest ten thousandth. print('Women: {:.2f} calories_women')
print('Men: {:.2f} calories_men')
Hope that helps the next student out because the struggle is definitely REAL

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I actually made this lab harder that what it was. Here is what you need:
Calories = ((Age x 0.2757) + (Weight x 0.03295) + (Heart Rate x 1.0781) — 75.4991) x Time / 8.368

```
Age=float(input())
Weight=float(input())
Heart_Rate=float(input())
Time=float(input())

Calories = float((Age * 0.2757) + (Weight * 0.03295) + (Heart_Rate * 1.0781) - 75.4991) * Time / 8.368

print('Calories: {:.2f} calories'.format(Calories))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
age_years = int(input())
weight_lbs = int(input())
heart_rate = int(input())
time_min = int(input())

men_calories = ((age_years * 0.2017) + (weight_lbs * 0.09036) + 
(heart_rate * 0.6309) - 55.0969) * time_min / 4.184
women_calories = ((age_years * 0.074) - (weight_lbs * 0.05741) + 
(heart_rate * 0.4472) - 20.4022) * time_min / 4.184
print('Women: {:.2f} calories'.format(women_calories))
print('Men: {:.2f} calories'.format(men_calories))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).